# If statement syntax with Squarespace JSON templates

Tags: json, squarespace, jsontemplate

I am trying to evaluate a string in if statement using JSON templates.

This works:

```
{.if true}
  <h1>It is true</h1>
{.end}
```

However, this syntax breaks the page:

```
{.if "foo"=="bar"}
  <h1>Not true</h1>
{.end}
```

How do I compare strings using JSON templates?

Answer (score 3):

Squarespace solves this problem using the ".equal" predicate (I can't post the link due to not enough rep. points):

```
{.equal? foo "bar"}
  <h1>It's true</h1>
{.or}
  <h1>Not true</h1>
{.end}
```

where foo is the key to a value provided within the JSON data. If you only want the "false/not-equal" part of it, then it could be condensed to:

```
{.equal? foo "bar"}{.or}<h1>Not true</h1>{.end}
```

Now, in cases where "bar" contains a space, you'll need to use a different character than a space as a delimiter. From the [Squarespace Forums](http://answers.squarespace.com/questions/56375/does-equal-fail-on-comparisons-with-a-space):

> The solution then is to specify any other character as a delimiter
>   (one that won't be used in any other part of the string). For example,
>   this will work:
>
> {.equal?:categoryFilter:"Family Law"}
>
> You can see that instead of using a space after .equal?, I've used a :
>   (colon). That way, the space in your second argument "Family Law" is
>   treated correctly and not attempting to delimit the words into two
>   separate arguments.

Note: to see that data that is provided for a page, add "?format=json-pretty" to the url. [Here's an example](http://five-demo.squarespace.com/our-crew-five/?format=json-pretty).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is doable, and I'm sure you don't wanna harcode values like this especially on a template that defeats the purpose.

try:

```
{.if foo}
  <h1>Not true</h1>
{.end}
```

Comment: this errors out too: {.if foo=="some string"} can i get something like that working?

Comment: No that would not work you need a property `{.if foo.SomeString}`

Comment: @SeanPlusPlus basically it works with true or false, no comparison, so stored that bool somewhere then your good